# Magento gift wrap amount & shipping country variables

Tags: orders, checkout, onepage-checkout

does anyone know how to show the gift wrap amount & shipping country in order confirmation

currently found this code for subtotal :

```
<?php echo Mage::helper("core")->currency($order_details->subtotal) ?>

also to show the shipping country id, 

<?php $shipping_address_data = $order_details->getShippingAddress(); ?> 
<?php echo $shipping_address_data['country_id']; ?>
```

the rest variable, is hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like `$orderItem->getProduct()->getGiftWrappingPrice()`

what do you mean with shipping country?